# Number.isNaN doesn't exist in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, numbers, nan

Why does not IE support the **Number.isNaN** function? I can't use simple isNan instead of Number.isNaN 'cause these functions are different!
For example:

```
Number.isNaN("abacada") != isNaN("abacada") //false != true
```

I need to abstract string and number and check, is some var really contains **NaN** (I mean NaN constant, but not-a-number value like strings).

```
someobj.someopt = "blah"/0;
someobj.someopt2 = "blah";
someobj.someopt3 = 150;
for(a in someobj) if(Number.isNaN(someobj[a])) alert('!');
```

That code should show alert for 1 time. But if I will change Number.isNaN to isNaN, it will alert 2 times. There are differences.

May be there is some alternative function exists?

Comment: The current Preview Release of Internet Explorer supports this method, [along with many other Number built-ins](https://status.modern.ie/numberbuiltinses6). You can stream this browser to your desktop for testing purposes at http://remote.modern.ie.

Comment: Microsoft's Edge browser implements this. IE 11 does not as of currently.

Answer (score 22):

> Why does not IE support the **Number.isNaN** function?

That's rather off-topic for Stack Overflow, but according to [the MDN page for `Number.isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN), it's not defined in any standard — it's only in the draft spec for ECMAScript 6 — and Internet Explorer is not the only browser that doesn't support it.

> May be there is some alternative function exists?

Not really, but you can easily define one:

```
function myIsNaN(o) {
    return typeof(o) === 'number' && isNaN(o);
}
```

or if you prefer:

```
function myIsNaN(o) {
    return o !== o;
}
```

Comment: What is the difference between the `isNan` here and doing `o !== o`

Comment: @PaulS.: No difference. I'll add that as an alternative, thanks.

Comment: @ruakh Doesn't [isNaN()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) force the coercion of non-numeric values to numbers? It's of course true if both of you referred to [`Number.isNaN()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN).

Comment: @ComFreek: Yes, it does -- hence `Number.isNaN`, and the question, and this answer -- but I'm afraid I don't see what you're getting at?

Comment: @ruakh Sorry for the confusion, let me word it clearer: your [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26962341/number-isnan-doesnt-exists-in-ie/26962405?noredirect=1#comment42462872_26962405) is imho wrong because **there is** a difference between `isNaN (global)` and doing `o !== o`.

Comment: @ComFreek: I think you missed the word "here" in Paul S.'s comment. There is no difference between `isNaN(o)` and `o !== o` on the right-hand-side of an `&&` operator whose left-hand-side is `typeof(o) === 'number'`, since in that context the type coercion is necessarily a no-op.

Comment: `typeof` - is an operator, but not a function, so the round brackets are redundant there.

Answer (score 1):

You need use isNaN without "Number." Like this:

`for(a in someobj) if(isNaN(someobj[a])) alert('!');`

This also work fine for chrome.

You can find more on microsoft site https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/isnan-function-javascript